# symfony bundle as git submodule

Tags: git, symfony, git-submodules

I have two symfony2 projects with some bundles, theses project are under git management.

Those 2 projects have 1 bundle in common, I want to make this bundle a submodule in order to merge the differences between project A and project B.

I'v read this: [Splitting directory into a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312333/splitting-directory-into-a-submodule) but i don't really understand how it works as the official git page (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) refer the command : `git submodule add`

So, how can I merge the two version of the commomBundle using submodules ?
Will a commit to projectA or projectB allso commit the change for submodules ?

Comment: I didn't thought about it ... It seems like I wont be able to merge the two commonBundle versions, also there is few application specific code in this bundle, using composer will I be able to add such specification and after get updates without loosing previous changes ?

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood your question, my apologies.

Comment: aaah, extract all application specific code from it either to config parameters or a child bundle. The common bundle will a git project, referenced via composer.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you will commit then push the shared project (lets call it Project S) from Project A or Project B (the two main roots projects with Project S inside) you'll then be able to merge since there will be two heads or two branches.

In order to merge you'll have to commit/push from both projects then from github (or another) you can merge (https://help.github.com/articles/merging-branches) or inside one of your projects (by pulling changes).

I hope i understanded well what you are looking for.